# TSQL Select all data for records in a history chain

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of insurance policies stored in a database.  If a policy is a renewal, I have a table that connects the policy to its previous (renewed) policy.  The tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Policies]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [SomeData] [int] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [PriorPolicies]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Policies](ID),
    [PriorID] [int] NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Policies](ID)
)
```

Given a policy, I want to write a query that gets `SomeData` for every policy in the history.  IE: If policy 8 is a renewal of policy 4 which is a renewal of policy 1, I want to get `SomeData` for policies 1, 4, and 8.  They should each be displayed as their own records and not be aggregated.

How can I accomplish this using TSQL?

Note: I know there is a better way to represent this data.  We should have an `Insured` table with unique insureds and then the policy table could have an `InsuredID` foreign key.  Then getting the historical chain would require only a select query on the `InsuredID`.  Unfortunately, that is not how I receive the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will get you 8, 5, and 1 given that 5 is prior to 8, and 1 is prior to 5:

```
WITH CTE (ID, SomeData)
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        SomeData
    FROM Policies
    WHERE
        ID = 8

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        P.ID,
        P.SomeData
    FROM CTE
    INNER JOIN PriorPolicies AS PP
        ON CTE.ID = PP.ID
    INNER JOIN Policies AS P
        ON P.ID = PP.PriorID
)
SELECT
    ID,
    SomeData
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a CTE.  Assuming you want to get all the history for policy 5 this should do it:

```
WITH PolicyChain (PrevID, FinalId) as
(
  select PriorID, ID
  from PriorPolicies
  union all
  select p.PriorID, pc.FinalID
  from PriorPolicies p
  inner join PolicyChain pc on pc.PrevID = p.ID
)
select p.*
from Policies p
inner join PolicyChain pc on pc.PrevID = p.ID
where pc.FinalId = 5
union all
select *
from Policies
where Id = 5
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5747c/11)

Comment: Thanks. While this works and you are the first to answer, I think pyrrosa's answer is better. It is more intuitive as it better defines the anchor of the CTE. In addition, it also includes the final policy in its result without having to do an extra union.